# Updating localstorage with button click

Tags: javascript

I need to update single item of object in localstorage without reloading page.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7xsg8679/

Here is my code:

```
if (obj.isCompletedTask === false) {
    newDone.innerHTML = "Not done";
    newDone.dataset.done = false;

    newButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        newDone.innerHTML = "Done";
        newDone.dataset.done = true;
        newUl.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}
```

If I use `if(obj.isCompletedTask === true)` in the if-statement - it does nothing. Why?

Comment: I believe you don't mean `window.localStorage`. Your code does not refer to localstorage in any way. Also, is obj.isCompletedTask and obj.isCompleted the same thing? Please try to be more explanative.

Comment: Yeah, I meant isCompletedTask. Sorry for the mistake. At this moment when I click the button, full list is showing up with the "Not done" statement and false. And I would like to change false to true with newButton.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what are you trying to do, what fires the code above, what exactly is not working?  Where is your attempt to update localstorage? Don't know how this got upvoted.

Comment: @JohnBra I have edited your post fixing this ìsCompletedTask` but it is still totally unclear what you want to achieve and what is precisely your problem.

Comment: I don't know how can I update isCompletedTask in localstorage. At this moment when I'm adding something to the list it is showing false in localstorage. I just wanna change single element of the list by clicking button.

Comment: @JohnBra do you mean this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage localStorage?

Comment: I set the list: localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(tasks)); Then I wanna  change single element. In this situation isCompletedTask.

Comment: Why didn't you include this piece of code in your question in a first place?

Comment: I added my code to jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7xsg8679/2/

Comment: you should not remove code and replace it with jsfiddle. The latter is only meant to help people solve your problem. Code is to be read here, in place.

Comment: Okay, I will remember this.

Comment: Spox. I've updated my answer. Check it and let me know if there's anymore you would like to have clarified.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that. But where exactly in the code do I have to set replaced list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `obj.isCompletedTask === true` the button does nothing `isCompletedTask` is false, so the code between curly brackets `{ ... }` is not run at all, so the eventListener does not get attached to your button click event.

You may want to move your if statement to inside of event listener, if i understood your intentions correctly.

---

When you want to update an element in localstorage, you do it like that:

```
localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(tasks));
```

...but when your `tasks` object changes, you need to keep a track of that yourself, and manually update localStorage. This relation is called data-binding. Moreover, you cannot just update subelement of your `tasks` directly, you have to replace `list` in localStorage with fresh version of `tasks` every time something in `tasks` changes.`

---

**General remark:** from what i see in your fiddle, i do really think you should have a look at some framework (like vue, react or angular). Keeping track of the changes here and there will really be tiresome after a while and besides, why should yo reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try to search for frameworks in the future.